# What is the Countif code for time range and date today? Thanks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

How can I simplify my code below without the hassle of updating the date every single day?

=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A2:A5797,">=1/3/2019 7:00",Sheet2!A2:A5797,"<=1/3/2019 8:00",Sheet2!D2:D5797,"Resolved")

I should have a result when 3 conditions are met, like the time, date, and status(Resolved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest feeding the date-times as parameters, say:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A2:A,">="&I1,Sheet2!A2:A,"<="&J1,Sheet2!D2:D,"Resolved")
```

so the results are determined by what you put in cells, rather than how you adapt a formula.

Then you might split dates and times as it seems it may only be the date you wish to change, thus say:

I1: `=E1+F1` and J1: `=G1+H1`

where E1 and G1 are dates and F1 and H1 times.

Then if the times are always during the same day as one another: G1: `=E1`.

And if some automation is required, possibly:

E1:- `=today()`, or perhaps `=today()+n`, where *n* is an integer offset of choice.